# Invariant Violation: TurboMoudleRegistry.getEnforcing:'AppState' could not be found.Verify that module by this name is registered in native binary

Tags: react-native, expo

> This error appears after ejecting expo project to bareflow react native project **v0.61.5.**
>   I have tried finding implementation for AppState in project but could't find any.
>   I am running my project with react-native run-android after react-native start

Comment: Found any solution?